# Proof Fragment and Questions

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Consider the following proof fragment.

There exists an integer k such that $n=3k+1$. 
Then $n^2=(3k+1)^2=9k^2+6k+1=3(3k^2+2k)+1$

For each of the statements (a), (b), (c) below, answer the following. If yes, explain why. If no, explain why not. The letter $n$ denotes an integer.

(a) If $n$ is odd, then $n^2$ is odd. 
(b) If $n^2$ is divisible by $3$, then $n$ is divisible by $3$. 
(c) If $n$ leaves remainder $1$ on division by $3$, then so does $n^2$.

Now what I did was computed a few values from $-4$ to $5$. 
(a) for example, holds because squaring an odd will get an odd 
(b) does not hold cause we are always taking one more than a multiple of 3; therefore, $n^2$ cannot be divisible by $3$. 
(c) holds because in essence, we are just minusing $1$ and $3k+1-1=3k$ and $3k$ is a multiple of 3 which would make its square a multiple of 3.

Fairly certain by logic is sound. But question: would giving examples be proof enough? Or would I need to generalize it? If I need to generalize it, how? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Giving examples is *not* good enough.  So a) is not acceptable.  You must explain *why* squaring an odd gives an odd.  b) how do you know (3k+1)^2 is not a multiple of 3.  You must explain why.  c) you must explain why.

Comment: Notice b) is actually true.  In this example, $n^2$ is *never* divisible by 3 so the sentence is vacuusly true.  In other examples $n^2$ can often be divisible by 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try and formalize part (b) a bit:

Since $n^2=(3k+1)^2=9k^2+6k+1=3(3k^2+2k)+1$, we know that $3$ cannot divide $n^2$, since it divides $n^2-1$.

Since $p \implies q$ and $\neg p$  what can you say about the truth value of this type of statement, more generally? The "if" part of your statement is always false.

for a quick proof of the my statement:
 Suppose $p$ is prime and that $p \mid k$. Then $k=pr$ for some $r \in \mathbb{Z}$. Suppose $p \mid k+1$, then $k+1=pl$ for some $l \in \mathbb{Z}$. But then $1=k+1-k=pl-pr=p(l-r)$ so $p \mid 1$. Since $3 \neq 1$, my first statement stands.

---

For part (a), your logic is not sound. If $n=3k+1$, we could easily let $k=1$, meaning that $n=3+1=4$ which is even. You should think a lit bit more about why (a) could hold (as in, do the algebra)

---

For part (c), yes it holds *kind of* for the reason you mention. If $n=3k+1$, it will always leave a remainder of one upon division by $3$, and the algebra you did shows that $n^2$ will as well.

---

**Rule of thumb:** more or less, the only time a "proof by example" works is when it is a counter-example. If you wish to prove a statement false, one example will suffice.

For example, the statement (c) is saying that $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}\, s.t \, n=3k+1$ we know that $n^2=3m+1$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Of course, to show something is true **for all** anything, examples will not suffice.